# New question from election chat for our 2021 moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

As the comments have been locked on the nominations, if you have questions for the candidates, you should post it here on meta and tag it with [election](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election). You could also ask in the election chat room, but the candidates might not see it.

I'll start us out by paraphrasing a question [Fattie asked in election chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59450220#59450220):

**Candidates, please explain in a few words your qualifications (perhaps academic) regarding English?**

Comment: Might be an idea to add a link to each candidate along with their nomination. Thankfully, we now have four candidates. May the best person  be elected.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think it's odd that only one of our candidates has responded to the question. I'd like to know other candidates are keeping an eye on meta even if they only say "I don't think academic credentials in English are important to being a good moderator."

Comment: Well, that was a surprise. For me the election was between AIQ and gotube. Remind me never to go into politics :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thought it was between AIQ and AIQ :) My guess is most voters just looked at Void's 33/40 score and voted based on that because reading is hard.

Comment: @gotube I looked at Void's candidate score (I never pay attention to that sort of thing, when I vote for someone I rely more on a user's contributions and participation) and saw it is/was 16/40. In light of recent events, you might yet be asked to be a moderator. Good luck :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Recent events"? Also, I'm positive Void's score appeared as 33/40 during the election. Why does it say 16/40 now??

Comment: @gotube did you not know? Void's moderatorship has been removed. He is currently suspended. I'd presume that the candidate who arrived second would be next in line.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Just reading about it now in chat. High drama! I'd presume the ballot counting would be calculated again from the start, with Void being eliminated in the first round as if they'd gotten the lowest count of first votes. With Void's voters distributed among the other candidates according to their second choices, mathematically, any other candidate could still win.

Comment: @gotube You were right, I did a little search and found this leaderboard query, it shows the scores of ELL users. Void has a score of (did?) 33/40 https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1467000/election-candidate-score-leaderboard. 17 score based on rep and 19 based on badge count.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the election is over.

Answer (score 5):

I do not have any academic qualifications (i.e., degrees or diplomas) related to the English language. I have learnt English mainly through unconventional means.

I have taken standardized tests: IELTS, GRE.

Other English test/exams: O Level English

Comment: Did you have to pass an English proficiency test to study in Canada? I think you have a unique perspective as a fluent non-native speaker that probably trumps formal training.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, just IELTS. But I've also taken the GRE voluntarily to secure additional funding/scholarships.

Comment: Well, I think that's a pretty strong endorsement of your English ability

Comment: @ColleenV Those are tests that any non-native can pass just by memorizing certain things. They do not reflect my English abilities, in my opinion. I don't want people to judge my abilities based on the fact that I took the IELTS. Honestly, it was so long ago, too - in 2016! I don't really consider them as qualifications; to me, a BA/MA in English or Linguistics is more like a qualification (which takes years to complete).

Comment: I think you are underestimating what you had to learn to pass those tests, and how likely it would be for a native speaker to do well on them.  A degree in linguistics doesn't make someone a good teacher. Regardless, while a moderator needs to be fluent, there's nothing wrong with having a moderator that asks more questions than they answer. The important part of the job is unrelated to the site's topic.

Comment: I have some experience with IELTS and I can say quite confidently that it is a qualification and  if someone gets an 8.5 or higher on the IELTS test that is practically native level. It's not just memory, there's the listening and the speaking paper too. Earning over 7.5 is really hard.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, and I don't think a mod need get anything near those scores!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I started learning the basics (alphabets, numbers, and certain words) when I was very young. Maybe 6 or 7.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of academic qualifications, I hold a Bachelor's degree in Linguistics, I have a Trinity CertTESOL certificate (the highest standard TESL certificate, equivalent to CELTA), and I am a certified Trinity CertTESOL trainer, specializing in grammar and pronunciation.

If experience counts as a qualification, I was a successful teacher of English as a Second Language (ESL) for 16 years to students of all levels from beginner to near-native, in kindergartens, universities, adult language schools and in private businesses. I've been a teacher of a variety of things my whole life. Every job I've had, and every hobby I've been serious about, I've ended up the trainer.

Comment: What do you mean by "the highest standard TESL certificate"? It's not a DipTESOL, so I'm struggling to understand what that means.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore Among standard 110-120 hour TESL certificates (not diplomas), Trinity and CELTA certificates are considered a tier above the others. If I recall correctly, it's because they include a mandatory foreign language learning module, where the trainee has to learn a new language using the techniques they've learned for teaching English.